# How to solve several instances of 'styled-components' with Vite

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem in react? I'm using vite react (not webpack).

It looks like there's two instances of **styled-components** in different libraries.

Here is an example:

`$ npm ls styled-components`

```
budgetapp@0.0.0 C:\Users\rootuser\OneDrive\Desktop\node\react\BudgetApp
├─┬ react-data-table-component@7.5.3
│ └─┬ styled-components@5.3.11
│   └─┬ babel-plugin-styled-components@2.1.3
│     └── styled-components@5.3.11 deduped
└─┬ react-pro-sidebar@1.0.0-alpha.7
  └── styled-components@5.3.11 deduped
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by aliasing it.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: 'styled-components': require.resolve('styled-components')
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I was having this issue when using npm-link and styled-components and this resolved it.